# What are JScript case sensitivity rules?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript

I am using the ScriptControlClass, for reference and I thought JScript was case sensitive...  However, my user base has surprised me...  I have several methods I have provided the users in all upper such as: IF, EMPTY, AGE, PARSE, etc...

Well, today a user filed a defect that issampgroup was not working.  I investigated and informed the user that the function was ISSAMPGROUP and that it was working correctly...  The user responded with, all the other functions except IF worked in lower case. So I ran a quick test and all but 5 of my functions work in a case insensitive manner...  I was very surprised to see age and Age as well as all other variations work and work correctly.  Below is a sample of how my functions are declared and I verified that Jscript function is calling my C# each time…

```
this.scriptEngine.AddCode(@"function AGE (birthDate) { return cmd.Age(birthDate); };");
this.scriptEngine.AddCode(@"function ISSAMPGROUP (value) { return cmd.IsSampleGroup(value); };");
```

Which leaves me confused as to why some functions work in a case insensitive manner and other do not.  For example, AGE is case insensitive, yet ISSAMPGROUP is case sensitive.

Comment: Is it supposed to be ISSAMPGROUP or ISSAMPLEGROUP? This might not be a case-sensitivity thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this one is quite simple - JavaScript *is* case sensitive, but browser manufacturers may decide to implement their JavaScript engine in such a way to make it more forgiving where possible.

So you should treat JavaScript as highly case-sensitive and anything that works with incorrect case should still be corrected as vendor-to-vendor script engines may differ and it may not work in all browsers, just the most forgiving browsers.

You have also highlighted how ALL CAPS isn't great for naming things, especially with abbreviations.

```
function IsSampleGroup
```

Has to be easier to read than

```
function ISSAMPGROUP
```

The reason some may work and others may not could be down to naming conflicts, i.e. whether there is another similarly named object in your JavaScript. MyVariable and myVariable and MYVARIABLE.

Comment: Was trying to implement an legacy script engine with Java Script.  So I was stuck with the bad casing and naming.  The wide variance in engine implementation meant I was unable to use the Java Script engine and had to build a new engine for the legacy language. :(

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript **IS** case sensitive.  As already mentioned some browsers do not always take this into consideration but as a rule you should try to always code for case and scope sensitivity to prevent issues.